# Issue with Unity build in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble getting an Xcode project exported from Unity to build correctly. When I attempt to create an ad hoc [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa) file, I get this error (apparently, it has something to do with [ArcGIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcGIS)):

> ld: unknown file type in '/Users/me/myproject/Frameworks/ARM64/Assets/Plugins/ArcGIS/Binaries/iOS/arm64/Runtimecore.framework/Runtimecore' 
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm not getting this on my other Mac that's using Xcode 14.3. What's going on here?

Here is my system information:

[Mac Mini (M1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Mini#Fifth_generation_(Apple_silicon)) ([Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)) 
[macOS v13.5.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) 
[Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) 2022.3.10f1 
Xcode 15 (15A240d)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the version of Xcode I was using. Apparently this version of the ArcGIS plugin does not work well with Xcode 15. Downgrading to 14.3 fixed it.